# How do I proportionally compare images with .animate()?

Tags: javascript

Below is code that compares two images with eachother in size. It uses the `.animate()` method for this. It works fine but there's one problem, sometimes the multiplication factor in this line is `var multiply = val * 2;` can get much higher than 2 and it blows up the second image out of the window frame.

A solution would be that at that point when it starts to become too big for the screen, it freezes the maximum size of the second picture and starts to shrink the first picture instead so it maintains an accurate proportionate comparison. How do I do that?

```js
var val = 100;

$("#enlarge").click(function(){
var multiply = val * 2;
$("#whitesphere1").animate({height:val,width:val});
$("#whitesphere2").animate({height:multiply,width:multiply})
});
```

```css
#comparison {
  position: absolute;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 300px;
 width: 500px;
}

#whitesphere1, #whitesphere2 {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 80px;
 width: 80px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

div img { width:100%; height:100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="enlarge">Enlarge</button>

<div id="comparison">
   <div id="whitesphere1"><center><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Sphere-with-blender.png"/></center></div>
   <div id="whitesphere2"><center><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Sphere-with-blender.png"/></center></div>
</div>
```

Comment: im not seeing the problem you mentioned in the OP

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   and read the section about "creating a minimal, verifiable example"  (  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )  -- this one appears to not be verifiable.

Comment: I'm saying the "problem", it's more a feature I'd like to have, is that when you say the multiply factor is something like 20, that the second image gets too big for the canvas as demonstrated in here. https://jsfiddle.net/cd684sLz/ What I'm trying to find out is how to prevent is going outside the canvas limits and from then starts to decrease first image size to the point where the size relation is proportionally accurate

Comment: Calculate the furthest point of the circle/sphere by taking the center point and then adding  the radius to it, and until the length of the radius becomes larger than the distance between the top right corner of the canvas and the middle of the sphere, you can keep growing the sphere..

Comment: use sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)    to get the distance between two points where x1,y1 = center of sphere, x2,y2 = top right corner of canvas.

Comment: btw stackoverflow isnt a code writing service -- its a "help you with your code that you have already written"  service

Comment: Thanks. I didn't necessarily want the code, I just wanted some direction as to how to take this on. I would never have guessed how to come to the math conclusion you just did.

Comment: I just thought about it visually -- your canvas is so many pixels  large, and the "radius" of a circle is represents the distance from the center to the edge of the circle.  therefore,  if the radius is larger than the distance from the top right corner to the center, then the circle will by definition have an edge further than the top right corner... I dunno made sense to me haha